# How to create a light weight docker image using redhat based base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, redhat-containers

- I am creating a docker image of a maven project. I want to run the
  jar file through that docker container. The main requirement is to
  use Redhat based base image and the size of the final image should be
  minimum. I have tried using:
- ubi9/ubi-minimal => it uses microdnf but the final image size is
  above 500MB ubi9/ubi-micro => it does not have yum/dnf, so could not
  use it ubi9/ubi => image size is above 600MB

  How can I create a Dockerfile using any redhat based base image to
  run a maven jar, which eventually creates a lightweight final image?

Answer (score 0):

```
docker pull redhat/ubi8-minimal
```

Try this.

Comment: redhat/ubi8-minimal is there at docker.io. I need to take the base image only from registry.redhat.io. Can you suggest any such image?